# Fill multiple IE WebForms in parallel with Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm developing an Excel Macro (VBA) which automatically fills an Internet Explorer WebForm with some user data from an Excel Sheet.

Currently the Script works sequentiell. So an IE instance is spinned up, the form is filled with the user data and submited. After that the IE instance is closed. The process will be repeated until all users are processed.

To speed up the process it would be better to spin up multiple IE instances at once and fill the user data in parallel. 
So how can I run multiple processes/IE instances in VBA?

Comment: Have multiple IE windows open at the same time and cycle through each window adding the info relevant ie user name to all then password etc.

Comment: @SolarMike I don't see how this comment solves my question. I already wrote that spinning up multiple instances is needed to solve this issue - my question was    on HOW to do this with Excel VBA

Comment: You wrote that each instance is opened, written then closed... I made the point that you can have several open at the same time and write the same info to each ie using a loop. If you are expecting someone to write the code then just give it to you ... good luck. Most people who post on here show effort in what they have built so far and then they get help...

Comment: As you cannot open multiple IE instances in parallel via VBA, and you cannot fill each IE instance of a theoretical set of instances at the same time, how should that be possible. You did not provide any code, but somehow I assume you declared variables e.g. for username etc., and use that to fill each form, true? I dealt with similar issues, but to my knowledge, you cannot solve that other than looping each time.

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not expecting someone to write code for me. My problem here is that afaik running multiple IE instances and filling them at once would require some kind of multi-threading. So my question was adressing this kind of general problem. Offending you was not the intention of my first comment - I apologize if it did.

Comment: Create some quantity of IE instances and put them into array. Loop through the array multiply times, check if IE state is ready then start to submit next user's data, and continue with the next IE instance immediately. Continue looping until all users' data submit. If necessary close and open the IE instance before new submitting. Be aware that there could be cookies interference that might not allow the webpages to work in right way simultaneously. Then you may resort to an HTTP request with cookies processing, i. e. `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` or `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1`.

Comment: @omegastripes ok thank you this is the best approach
You can put your comment as an answer and I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create some quantity of IE instances and put them into array. Loop through the array multiply times, check if IE instance's state is ready then start to submit next user's data, and continue with the next IE instance immediately. Continue looping until all users' data uploaded. If necessary close and open the IE instance before new submitting. Do not forget to add `DoEvents` statement into the loop.

Be aware that there could be cookies interference, etc. that might not allow the webpages to work in right way simultaneously. Then you may resort to an HTTP request approach with cookies processing, i. e. `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` or `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1`.